# Using Web Application created with Netbeans in Tomcat?

Tags: web-services, tomcat, web-applications, netbeans

Sorry I newbie.

How to use Web Application ( with Web Services) created with Netbeans in my Tomcat that was manually installed?

I want to use my WA in my Tomcat (this tomcat wasn't installed with Netbeans).

My Tomcat is 8.0.3 version...

My Netbeans is:

**Product Version**: NetBeans IDE 8.0 (Build 201403101706)
**Updates**: Updates available to version NetBeans 8.0 Patch 2
**Java**: 1.8.0_05; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 25.5-b02
**Runtime**: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_05-b13
**System**: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on x86; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

I was following http://docs.huihoo.com/netbeans/6.0/kb/60/websvc/jax-ws.html.
I decided to use this old version because this link (newer version) https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html is oriented to **Glassfish**.

Now I want to test my Web Services in Tomcat, I was thinking that I need to copy my folder named: **CalculatorWSApplication** to **webapps\ROOT** tomcat's folder, trying to do smothing like:

IPofMyHost:8080/CalculatorWSApplication/

or

IPofMyHost:8080/CalculatorWSApplication/CalculatorWS

I'm very lost

Answer (score 0):

you can tell netebans you have tomcat (menu->tools->server->add server...)
and then configure you project to run with tomcat (project->properties->run->server...)

Or, after building you app in netbeans, just copy the .war file to the tomcat "webapps" folder.
Tomcat will do the deploy for you.